# Word for "a person so bad that people use him for negative publicity of something"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, pejorative-language

I am looking for terse phrase/word that describes a person who has such a bad reputation that to do negative publicity of any product, the competitor pays this person to speak praise of it.

Comment: Can you cite any examples? I'd have thought if the "maligned" company could prove that a competitor had paid someone to "praise" their product in that way, they'd have an open-and-shut case for legal action.

Comment: ... related is a nice little "eggcorn" that I hadn't come across before - [*to damn with **feigned** praise*](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=106544)

Comment: @Fumble Fingers The Google ngrams thing, for what that's worth, couldn't find any examples at all of anyone 'damning with feigned praise' though plenty with 'faint'. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=damn+with+faint+praise%2C+damn+with+feigned+praise&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdamn%20with%20faint%20praise%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @FumbleFingers Re 'open and shut case for legal action'; what would  they actually charge them with? I'm not sure if 'defamation' would work. Interesting one for a solicitor if we have one here.

Comment: @WS2: Right behind you there, mate! There's something rather "oxymoronic" about the concept of "defamation of an MP's character". As regards the *feigned praise* - I know it's of limited currency (I'd never come across it before), but it jumped out at me when I Googled whatever terms I thought of for OP's context (I can't recall what they were now).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming:

1. The person with the reputation was not a user of the praised product before being paid by its company's competitor
2. The competitor's product/business is inferior to that of the maligned
3. The ad's negativity may or may not exceed the [guilt by association](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_fallacy) caused by associating the bad person with the praised product

then it may be fitting to call the person of ill repute a [***plant***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/plant), which TFD defines as

> 4.) A person or thing put into place in order to mislead or function secretly, especially:
>
> 1. A person placed in a group of spectators to influence behavior.

There is also [***shill***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shill), which TFD defines as

> One who poses as a satisfied customer or an enthusiastic gambler to dupe bystanders into participating in a swindle.

related to the verb [*to shill*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shill) defined by MW as

> to talk about or describe someone or something in a favorable way because you are being paid to do it

And if the competitor tries in any way to hide their connection to the negative ad, [WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shill) suggests *shill* may still be used (though *plant* is mentioned in a scenario that sounds closer to the one in OP's question)

> A shill... is a person who publicly helps a person or organization without disclosing that they have a close relationship with the person or organization.... [But terms like "**plant**" and "**stooge**"] more commonly refer to any person who is secretly in league with another person or organization while pretending to be neutral or actually a part of the organization he is planted in.

Even in the best-case scenarios I can come up with, *plant* and *shill* still seem appropriate; though in some cases, words like [*stooge*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stooge?s=t), [*puppet*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/puppet?s=t), or [*pawn*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pawn) -- with their connotations of the person of bad repute being manipulated, secondary, or somehow lesser -- seem harsh but fair, because the *shill* is (presumably voluntarily and knowingly) choosing to live off of (and perhaps revel in) the public's poor opinion of who he is.

Comment: +1 for *shill*. I knew that one, but I'd forgotten it. I think it's better than *plant*, because it seems more specific to OP's exact context. A *plant* can cover a much broader range of deceptions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Agreed. When I hear *plant* I tend to think of something more covert, like being a *mole* or listening in on a phone call through a planted bug. The Wiki description may have talked me out of *shill* as primary answer, but it's still the one I back the most.

Comment: Would you include `toady` along with stooge, shill, and plant?

Comment: @Marc: Good question. *Toady* can have a similar self-disrespect to what I see in *stooge*, *pawn*, etc. But I think the question here would be: Who is the person a *toady* toward? The company they fawn over, the competitor who pays them, or both? The part I like about *plant* and *shill* is that they can point directly to mixed allegiances or conflicts-of-interest, where *toady* may require more explanation to make that connection.

Comment: @dingo_dan: I don't know what "Wiki description" you're referring to, but OED's ***shill** - a decoy or **accomplice**, esp. one **posing** as an enthusiastic or **successful customer** to **encourage** other **buyers**, gamblers, etc.* seems a whole lot more on-target than any feasible definitions for ***plant, toady, stooge, pawn*** or whatever. OP's exact sense still sounds weird to me (and we have no actual examples), but I don't see how any other definition could get much closer.

Answer (score 1):

Try "notorious" or "infamous".